# CurrentApp.ReportConsumableFulfillmentAsync vs CurrentApp.ReportProductFulfillment

Tags: windows-phone-8, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I have to implement "in-app purchase" both for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8 app. The API looks the same for both platforms, besides one method: "CurrentApp.ReportProductFulfillment" (only WP has it). However, both platforms have "CurrentApp.ReportConsumableFulfillmentAsync".

My preference is to write fully reusable code (same code) for both platforms, if possible. MSDN documentation is not clear enough, so I want to understand:

1. Can I use ReportConsumableFulfillmentAsync on WP instead of ReportProductFulfillment? Are they have the same functionality? (maybe they left ReportProductFulfillment for backward compatibility).
2. Do I have to call ReportConsumableFulfillmentAsync after buying consumable only, or after every store purchase?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp.reportconsumablefulfillmentasync) ReportConsumableFulfillmentAsync is Windows Phone 8.1 API, so you cannot use it when creating Windows Phone 8 apps. Stick with ReportProductFulfillment and Windows Phone 8 apps for now, it will take some time for Windows Phone 8.1 to get on the market
2. Only for consumables

If your are looking or a nice in-app wrapper, take a look at this https://github.com/igorkulman/Kulman.WP8/blob/master/Kulman.WP8/Services/WindowsPhoneStoreService.cs

Comment: Thanks you, the wrapper is very useful. I just want to note that (I think, need to check) this have to be called on UI thread.